# Game center sandbox

Tags: sandbox, game-center, achievements, leaderboard

Ok, so I have an app available in the app store, for its next update I want to add Game Center functionality, I have done all my coding and everything is working as I would expect (using NSLog to make sure that the correct coding is called) but, when I open up Game Center, one achievement is there but not the second one that I got and one of the leader boards was showing a score a few hours ago, now its not and on the other leaderboard the score is showing as an old score.
is the Game Center Sandbox mode really this bad as I have been searching for errors in my code for hours now and I swear, there arent any.
Can anyone help me please?
Note - I saw on here someone suggested to use the game with 2 game center accounts, I have done that and on the second account no highscore or achievements are showing at all.

Thanks Graham

Answer (score 0):

In my experience two accounts do seem to be necessary and you have to wait a while (sometimes hours or overnight) for results to appear. Other times they appear quicker. I actually tested with 3 accounts but I doubt the third made any difference.

And double check that the leaderboard ID in iTunes Connect exactly matches the ID in your code.